# How to insert a new node into a binary tree?

Tags: scala, binary-tree

How to insert a node into a binary tree with respect to this code:

```
import util.Random
import collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.collection.mutable.Queue
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack

case class Node[K](value:K, var left:Option[Node[K]], 
                   var right:Option[Node[K]],var parent:Option[Node[K]]) {
    def hasLeft:Boolean = if (left!=None) true else false
    def hasRight:Boolean = if (right!=None) true else false
    def hasParent:Boolean = if (parent!=None) true else false
    def isLeaf:Boolean = !hasLeft && !hasRight
    def isParent(n:Node[K]):Boolean = {
        if (!isLeaf) {
            val l = if (hasLeft) left.get else null
            val r = if (hasRight) right.get else null
            l==n || r==n
        }
        else false
    }
}

abstract class BinaryTree[K] {
    def add(value:K)
    def remove(value:K):Boolean
    def height:Int
    def size:Int
}

class Tree[K](implicit ord:K=>Ordered[K]) extends BinaryTree[K] {
    var root:Option[Node[K]] = None
    private var count = 0
    override def add(value:K) {
        root match {
            case None => root = Some(new Node[K](value,None,None,None))
            case Some(node) => if(insert(node,value)) count+=1
        }
    }

    def insert(node:Node[K],newVal:K):Boolean= {
        if(newVal<node.value) {
            node match{
                case Node(_,None,_,_) => node.left = 
                    Some(new Node[K](newVal,None,None,Some(node))); true
                case Node(_,Some(left),_,_) => insert(left,newVal)
            }
        } else if(newVal>node.value) {
            node match{
                case Node(_,_,None,_) => node.right = 
                    Some(new Node[K](newVal,None,None,Some(node))); true
                case Node(_,_,Some(right),_) => insert(right,newVal)
            }
        } else false
    }

    override def remove(value:K):Boolean= {
        root match {
            case None => false
            case Some(node) => {
                binarySearch(value,node) match {
                    case None => false
                    case Some(node) => {
                        count-=1
                        delete(node)
                        true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    def delete(node:Node[K]) {
        node match {
            case Node(value,None,None,Some(parent)) => updateParent(parent,value,None)
            case Node(value,Some(child),None,Some(parent)) => {
                updateParent(parent,value,Some(child))
                child.parent = Some(parent)
            }
            case Node(value,None,Some(child),Some(parent)) => {
                updateParent(parent,value,Some(child))
                child.parent = Some(parent)
            }
            case Node(_,Some(child),None,None) => {
                root = Some(child)
                child.parent = None
            }
            case Node(_,None,Some(child),None) => {
                root = Some(child)
                child.parent = None
            }
            case Node(_,Some(left),Some(right),_) => {
                var child = right
                while(child.left!=None) {
                    child=child.left.get
                } 
                node.parent match {
                    case Some(parent) => updateParent(parent,node.value,Some(child))
                    case None => root = Some(child)
                }
                child.left = node.left
                child.right = node.right
                left.parent = Some(child)
                right.parent = Some(child)
                if (child.hasParent && child.parent.get.hasLeft && child.parent.get.left.get == child) 
                    child.parent.get.left=None
                else child.parent.get.right=None
                    child.parent = node.parent
                }
            case _ =>
        }

        def updateParent(parent:Node[K],value:K,newChild:Option[Node[K]]) {
            if(value<parent.value) parent.left = newChild
            else parent.right = newChild
        }
    }

    def binarySearch(value:K,node:Node[K]):Option[Node[K]]= {
        if (value==node.value) 
            Some(node)
        else if (value<=node.value) {
            node match {
                case Node(_,None,_,_) => None
                case Node(_,Some(left),_,_) => binarySearch(value,left)
            }
        } else {
            node match{
                case Node(_,_,None,_) => None
                case Node(_,_,Some(right),_) => binarySearch(value,right)
            }
        }
    }

    def inorder:Seq[K]= {
        val nodes = new ArrayBuffer[K]()
        val stack = new Stack[Node[K]]()
        if (size!=0) {
            var cur = root
            while(!stack.isEmpty || cur!=None) {
                cur match {
                    case Some(node) => {
                        stack.push(node)
                        cur = node.left
                    }
                    case None=> {
                        val tmp = stack.pop()
                        nodes += tmp.value
                        cur = tmp.right
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        nodes
    }

    def preorder:Seq[K]= {
        val nodes = new ArrayBuffer[K]()
        val stack = new Stack[Node[K]]()
        if (size!=0) {
            var cur = root
            while(!stack.isEmpty || cur!=None) {
                cur match {
                    case Some(node) => {
                        stack.push(node)
                        nodes += node.value
                       cur = node.left
                    }
                    case None=> {
                        val tmp = stack.pop()
                        cur = tmp.right
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        nodes
    }

    def postorder:Seq[K]= {
        val nodes = new ArrayBuffer[K]()
        val stack = new Stack[Node[K]]()
        if (size!=0) {
            var prev:Option[Node[K]] = None
            stack.push(root.get)
            while(!stack.isEmpty) {
                val cur = stack.top
                prev match {
                    case None=> if (cur.hasLeft) stack.push(cur.left.get) else if (cur.hasRight) stack.push(cur.right.get)
                    case Some(node)=>{
                        if(!cur.isParent(node) && cur.hasLeft) stack.push(cur.left.get)
                        else if (!cur.isParent(node) && cur.hasRight) stack.push(cur.right.get)
                        else if (cur.isParent(node) && cur.hasRight && cur.hasLeft && cur.left.get==node) stack.push(cur.right.get)
                        else {
                            stack.pop()
                             nodes+=cur.value
                        }
                    }
                }
                prev=Some(cur)
           }
        } 
        nodes
    }

    def postorder(node:Option[Node[K]]) {
        node match{
            case None=>
            case Some(n)=>{
                postorder(n.left)
                postorder(n.right)
                println(n.value)
            }
        } 
    }

    override def toString:String= {
        postorder.mkString(" : ")
    }

    override def height:Int= depth(root)

    def depth(node:Option[Node[K]]):Int = {
        node match {
            case None => 0
            case Some(n) => 1+ scala.math.max(depth(n.left),depth(n.right))
        } 
    }

    def prettyPrint(node:Option[Node[K]]):String= {
        if (node == None) ""
        else if(node.get.isLeaf) "\n\\t"+node.get.value.toString
        else node.get.value.toString+"\n\\t"+prettyPrint(node.get.left)+"\n\\t"+prettyPrint(node.get.right)
    }

    def bfs {
        val queue = new Queue[Option[Node[K]]]()
        queue.enqueue(root)
        while(!queue.isEmpty) {
            queue.dequeue match {
                case Some(node)=>{
                    println(node.value)
                    queue.enqueue(node.left)
                    queue.enqueue(node.right)
                }
                case None =>
            }
        }
    }   
    def size = count
}

object App {
    def main(args:Array[String]) {
        val generator = new Random()
        val tree = new Tree[Int]()
    //    (1 until 8).foreach(_=>tree.add(generator.nextInt(100)))
        tree.add(6)
        tree.add(3)
        tree.add(8)
        tree.add(2)
        tree.add(4)
        tree.add(8)
        tree.add(7)
        tree.add(9)
        tree.add(1)
        tree.add(5)
        tree.postorder(tree.root)
        println(tree)
        tree.bfs     
    }
}
```

Comment: I think, the question is too broad, and the amount of code is too high. Try to find which part is really hard to understand and ask about it. Or if you are really totally new to the language, maybe it's better to start with something simpler? try solving some tasks from projecteuler.net, for example. Or the classical "99 haskell problems", but in Scala.

Comment: @SargeBorsch I mean I just meant how to call that insert function inside main.

Comment: You wanted to say "insert method", right? From class `Tree`?

Comment: Also, if this is your code, consider keeping the formatting consistent. It's somewhat hard on eyes now. (there are lots of missing spaces, and they are omitted not consistently)

Comment: I guess it would be `tree.insert(something)` if the `tree` is your object in which you want to call `insert` method. did you try this and what went wrong?

Comment: @SargeBorsch Ya, I was doing something like tree.insert(node.value, 5) but it says: not found: value node :o

Comment: `def hasParent:Boolean = (parent!=None)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use 'insert' method in 'main' you can do it this way:

```
tree.root match{
    case None => tree.root = Some(new Node[Int](10,None,None,None))
    case Some(node) => tree.insert(node,10)
}
```

This code checks if tree has root. If there is root then node is insertet. If there is no root then root is created.

But you shouldn't do it. You shouldn't call this 'insert' method directly. This Tree class is designed smartly. It has 'add' method which is easy to use and is destined for you to use when you want to add value to the tree. 'insert' method is only helper method. This is recursive method used by 'add' method to insert value in the appropriate place.

So the only right way of adding something to this tree is by using 'add' method. Trying to add something by calling 'insert' method is like trying to start a car without using a key. You can do it but why if you have the key in front of you.